# Dynamically adding items to top of listview

Tags: android, listview

Is it possible to insert a ListView item to the top of the list, with the position of the most recent item going at the top? I am aware of other methods of achieving this, such as `items.add(0, item);`, `getItem(getCount() - position - 1);` as well as using `listView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);` within a `runnble()`, but the results are  [as shows in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bt0Rc.png), where the numbers represent  an `int position` index. New items added to the list are placed at the bottom, pushing all previous items upward.

I would like a result [like this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4BIo.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just reverse the list.

Comment: to the top or to the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own problem! Basically I used the method which involves placing each item in the list at index 0, `items.add(0, layer);` which visually, does indeed stacks the elements in my list, but at the cost of reversing the position index. All I needed to do was modify the recieved `int position` index so that it corresponds to the positions of the reversed list.

Answer (score 0):

You can't normally do this with listview. Try bottom sheet which is explained [here](https://medium.com/@emrullahluleci/android-bottom-sheet-30284293f066).